# Can I assign values from my collection in a string array..?? (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get values from name value collection and trying to store it in a string array

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = DataRowColl.GetValue[i];
}
```

DataRow.Coll is my namevaluecollection.
Its giving the error that reference without parentheses,
Can I assign values from my collection in a string array..??

Comment: Please post actual error. Are you also sure that `arr` and `DataRowColl` have the same number of elements?

Comment: I correct it, I was using square braces instead of (),
it should be
**arr[i] = Convert.ToString(DataRowColl.GetValue(i));**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetValue` is not a member of `NameValueCollection`. The function is called `Get`. If you want to use the `[]` operator, you don't have do call the `Get` function. So call

```
arr[i] = DataRowColl[i];
```

or:

```
arr[i] = DataRowColl.Get(i);
```

Comment: Ur second answer helped me,